# Image mosaic-ing in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, mosaic

I am trying to do some image analysis over tiles of a big tif image. I have already done the processing required in each of these tiles and in this step I have to create one mosaic out of these tifs. I read somewhere that I can use 'cat' function for this reason. As I am not really pro in programming I found it easy and tried to apply it. The tiles I have are about 154 tifs and I tried the cat over 4 of them and it works and now I should expand it over all the files. My problem now is to apply it over all the tifs. The codes for 4 of them was:

```
img1 = imread ('E:...\'a1.tif','tif');
img2 = imread ('E:...\'a2.tif','tif');
img3 = imread ('E:...\'a3.tif','tif');
img4 = imread ('E:...\'a4.tif','tif');

image1 = cat(2,img1,img3);

image2 = cat(2,img2,img4);

image3 = cat(1,image2,image1);
imshow(image3)
```

as you see in the code two by two should be stitch horizontally and the result would be stitch vertically to have the final image. M question is how through these amount of images I define which ones should be stitch first horizontally and then the resulted images stitch vertically. I would be really thankful if you guys could help me with it. Any other approaches would be welcome.

Comment: How were the tiles generated? Do they have any accompanying documentation? I would be very surprised if there isn't some kind of auxiliary file describing how they are arranged, or some convention which allows you to determine this given the file names / numbers.

Comment: the images actually have the coordinates where the name of each image is the upper left corner of that image. for instance '32511616,4_5403956,2.tif'. so I would say they are 11 series on the x direction and 14 series on the y direction.

Answer (score 0):

If tiles are of the same size you could concatenate them by operating on them as if they were plain matrices:

```
% dots-and-linebreak used for prettier formatting
concatenated_image = [ img1, img3; ...
                       img2, img4 ];
```

All tiles till `;` are concatenated horizontally in one row, and rows are concatenated vertically to form final image.

Applying this principle you could join any number of preloaded images by doing this:

```
NUMBER_OF_IMAGES = 152;   % divisible by 4
IMAGES_PER_LINE = 4;

concatenated_image = [];
for ii = 0 : (NUMBER_OF_IMAGES/IMAGES_PER_LINE)-1
    one_row = [];
    for jj = 1 : IMAGES_PER_LINE
        % concatenate next image in this line
        one_row = [ one_row eval(['img' num2str(4*ii+jj)]) ];
    end

    % add constructed row to the existing image
    concatenated_image = [ concatenated_image; one_row ];
end
```

Instead of using variables named like `imgN` you should prefer using *Matlab*'s cell arrays. You could then load all the images with:

```
imgs = {};
for ii = 1:154
    imgs{ii} = imread (['E:...\a' num2str(ii) '.tif'],'tif');
end
```

Then you would have to change the above concatenation code to:

```
...
one_row = [ one_row imgs{4*ii+jj} ];
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Well the code above does not include cat function. is that missing or the code is really like that. I also would like to ask that, you mean the horizontal tiles are separated by comma and the vertical ones are separated by semi column?

Comment: Code is exactly the way I wrote it. It doesn't need cat function, because you're using Matlab's native approach of constructing matrices. Yes, you separate tiles horizontally with *comma* or *whitespace characters*, and vertically with *semicolon*.

Comment: Dear zplesivcak : Thank you very much for your help and script. this is very thoughtful but I am having problem applying it for my files. well, the naming of my files are based on the upper left corner of each image. for instance it is :('32511616,4_5401556,2.tif','32512016,4_5402756,2.tif','32512016,4_5403156,2.tif','32512416,4_5401156,2.tif') where we have 11 rows and 14 columns. would you please guide me how can I change the script to apply it for my files?

Comment: Where in those names is the row and column number, I don't see it clearly. Could you use **bolding** to denote row and column numbers, and then I would be able to help you.

Comment: ok sorry I write the file names again. they would start with **'32511616,4_5401556,2.tif** and it would continue with the sequence of 400 on the north value to **'32511616,4_5401956,2.tif'** and it would go 14 times up to **'32511616,4_5405956,2.tif'**. then the naming would change by increasing in the east direction by **'32512016,4_5401556,2.tif'** it would again 14 times and this process would continue up to the end of which is : **'32515616,4_5405956,2.tif'**. I hope it is clear now a bit

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't invest that much effort to decode what you meant here. Try to write a bit clearer...

Comment: thank you for your effort to help. In understand maybe it is a bit complicated to arrange for the available files. Well may I ask what does the line  **one_row = [ one_row eval(['img' num2str(4*ii+jj)]) ];**   mean? I want to try to understand the rule of each line of the script and then try to reform it for my files.

Comment: I recommend you that you try every command in *Matlab*'s command prompt. For example, for the line you mentioned `one_row = [ one_row eval(['img' num2str(4*ii+jj)]) ];`, you could try: **1)** using array, try `a(1) = 3`, then `a(2) = 5`, then type just `a` **2)** type `help num2str` to see the documentation for the function (it converts number to string) **3)** try to type `['a' ' ' 'b' ' ' num2str(2)]` (this is used to concatenate strings, number must firstly be converted to string to be viable for concatenation) **4)** try `a = [1 2]`, then try `b = [a 3]`, then try `c = [b ; 4 5 6]`.